# plotting average of scatter dots belonging to the same class

Tags: python, matplotlib, deep-learning

I have created a scatter plot, similar to this *mnist* scatter plot of **Variational AutoEncoder (VAE)**.

[image: MNIST Mean plot for VAE]

The plot is generated as follows (the dimension of the z_mean is `(?,2)`):

```
plt.scatter(z_mean[:, 0], z_mean[:, 1], c=y_test)
```

Now, I'd like to plot the mean of all the plots belonging to the same class.
For example, if I have plotted the 10000 test samples of 10 classes, I'd like to plot the mean of all those plots belonging to the same class. So, just plot the 10 dots where each dot indicates one class (from 0 to 9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the means per y-value and store them into an array.

The following code first creates some random test data, shows a scatter plot with some transparency, calculates the means per group and then shows those means with a large dot. It also uses 'tab10' as colormap, which has more distinct colors than the default 'viridis'.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100
M = 10
z_mean = np.random.normal(np.tile(np.random.uniform(1, 10, 2 * M), N)).reshape(-1, 2)
y_test = np.tile(np.arange(M), N)

plt.scatter(z_mean[:, 0], z_mean[:, 1], c=y_test, cmap='tab10', alpha=.3)

ys = np.unique(y_test)
means = np.array([np.mean(z_mean[y_test == y, :], axis=0) for y in ys])
plt.scatter(means[:, 0], means[:, 1], c=ys, s=200, edgecolors='black', cmap='tab10')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]